# Tedious Nodejs, is there a way to get a row and column

Tags: node.js, tedious

```
function executeStatement() {
request = new Request("SELECT * FROM table;", function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

var resultSet = [];

request.on('row', function (columns) {
    var row = {};
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.isNull) {
            row[column.metadata.colName] = null;
        } else {
            row[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        }
    });
    console.log('Row is: ' + JSON.stringify(row));

    resultSet.push(row);
});

connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Hey Guys,

I have am having issues with this code.  I am trying to find away to get the row data and display.  for example getting row1-col2 to display...

The connection is working fine and pulling data from the database, I just need to be able to pull eg row1-col3

am i on the right track?

Thank you